# Continous Update of Python Qt Plot

Tags: python, pyside, pyqtgraph

Consider the sample PySide6 code below.
I have a class **SampleWindow** which generates some set of values  continuously (x and y).
I would also like to plot and visualize them parallelly, for which **ScatterPlotDialog** class has been writtten.
However, I am having issues with the continuos updating/refresh of the plot.

I am not sure if this is an issue of `pyqtgraph` OR it's a pythonic implementation issue.
Any suggestions to improve or solve the issue ?

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QDialog
import pyqtgraph as pg
import random


class ScatterPlotDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Scatter Plot Dialog")
        self.setup_ui()

        # Create initial empty scatter plot
        self.scatter_plot = pg.ScatterPlotItem()
        self.plot_widget.addItem(self.scatter_plot)

        # Set initial scatter plot data
        self.scatter_plot.setData(x=x, y=y)

    def setup_ui(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.plot_widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class SampleWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Sample Window")
        self.setup_ui()

        self.x = []  # Initialize x and y values as empty lists
        self.y = []

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_data)
        self.timer.start(1000)  # Update data every 1 second

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.button = QPushButton("Open Scatter Plot Dialog", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_scatter_plot_dialog)

    def update_data(self):
        # Generate new random data points and update x and y values
        self.x = [random.uniform(0, 10) for _ in range(10)]
        self.y = [random.uniform(0, 10) for _ in range(10)]

    def open_scatter_plot_dialog(self):
        dialog = ScatterPlotDialog(self.x, self.y)
        dialog.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = SampleWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: What do you get on plot? Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. Did you use `print()` to see which line of code is executed and what you have in variables?

Comment: you assign new value to `self.x` `self.y` in `SampleWindow` but you never send it to `ScatterPlotDialog`

Answer (score 1):

You assign new data to `self.x`, `self.y` in `SampleWindow`
but this will not update data in `dialog.scatter_plot`

You have to keep `dialog` as `self.dialog` in `open_scatter_plot_dialog` and use

```
def update_data(self):

    # ...

    self.dialog.scatter_plot.setData(x=self.x, y=self.y)
```

---

Because you start `QTimer` before you create `dialog`
so you may have to set `self.dialog = None` in `__init__`
and later check `if self.dialog:` before `self.dialog.scatter_plot.setData()`

---

Full working code:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QDialog
from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer
import pyqtgraph as pg
import random


class ScatterPlotDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Scatter Plot Dialog")
        self.setup_ui()

        # Create initial empty scatter plot
        self.scatter_plot = pg.ScatterPlotItem()
        self.plot_widget.addItem(self.scatter_plot)

        # Set initial scatter plot data
        self.scatter_plot.setData(x=x, y=y)

    def setup_ui(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.plot_widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class SampleWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Sample Window")
        self.setup_ui()

        self.x = []  # Initialize x and y values as empty lists
        self.y = []

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_data)
        self.timer.start(1000)  # Update data every 1 second

        self.dialog = None   # default value before you create this dialog
        
    def setup_ui(self):
        self.button = QPushButton("Open Scatter Plot Dialog", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_scatter_plot_dialog)

    def update_data(self):
        # Generate new random data points and update x and y values
        self.x = [random.uniform(0, 10) for _ in range(10)]
        self.y = [random.uniform(0, 10) for _ in range(10)]

        if self.dialog:  # check if dialog already exists
            self.dialog.scatter_plot.setData(x=self.x, y=self.y)

    def open_scatter_plot_dialog(self):
        self.dialog = ScatterPlotDialog(self.x, self.y)
        self.dialog.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = SampleWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```